# Alternate CSS in SharePoint online not loading in "Site Contents" and custom pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page

I have uploaded alternative CSS in SharePoint online site for HIDING navigation bar and title bar in master page, without touching/editing master page.

Correctly working in "Site Settings.aspx" page and "Home.aspx" page, but **NOT working in "Site Contents.aspx" page, lists, library and my custom pages**.

CSS i have uploaded in /_catalogs/masterpage

I don't know why this behavior. Please help me ASAP, its very urgent.